# Electron contextBridge not invoking function only when compiled

Tags: javascript, electron

Everything works fine on developer mode but **fails** to call the target function **only** when compiled.

I've stripped all of the functionality from the target function, I just want it to get into the function but it won't. Even I just wanted it to print just a hello world.

1. click listener

```
 saveValidationReport.addEventListener('click', () => {
     // const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.validationCheckbox');
     // const checkboxStates = Array.from(checkboxes).map(checkbox => {
     //   return { id: checkbox.id, checked: checkbox.checked };
     // });
      const checkboxStates = "caca";
      //console.log(checkboxStates); // Add this line
      //debugger;
      console.log("About to call saveValidationReport");
      window.api.saveValidationReport(checkboxStates);
      showNotification('Request saved successfully!', 'success');
    });
```

2. Part of the preload.js contextBridge

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
  openScripts: (scriptsPath) => ipcRenderer.send("openScripts", scriptsPath),
  getScriptsPathDev: async () => ipcRenderer.invoke("getScriptsPathDev"),
  getScriptsPathProd: async () => ipcRenderer.invoke("getScriptsPathProd"),
  saveResponseXml: async (data) => ipcRenderer.invoke("saveResponseXml"),
  invoke: (channel, data) => {
    return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, data);
  },
  fetchData,
  validationResponse,
  regenerateValidationReport,
  saveValidationReport: (checkboxes) => {
    ipcRenderer.invoke('callSaveValidationReport', checkboxes)},
```

(context bridge is actually longer and other functions are being invoked with no problem, it's just this one).

3. The actual function in index.js (I've stripped it from all the instructions). I just want it to throw a console.log but it won't.

```
ipcMain.handle('callSaveValidationReport', async (event, checkboxStates) => {
    console.log(checkboxStates); 
    log.info(checkboxStates);    
    console.log("Saving Campaign Report");
    // const regex = /assetid/i;
    // const checkboxStatusArray = [];
    
    // try {
    //   const appPath = app.getAppPath();
    //   const responseFilePath = path.join(appPath, "salesforceResponse.xml");
    //   log.info(`App path: ${appPath}`);
    //   log.info(`Response file path: ${responseFilePath}`);
    //   const data = await readFile(responseFilePath, "utf8");
    //   const result = await parseString(data);
  
    //   for (const checkbox of checkboxStates) {
    //     const checkboxId = checkbox.id.split("assetid");
    //     if (regex.test(checkbox.id)) {
    //       let providedAssetID = extractIntegerFromString(checkboxId[1]);
    //       await updateMergeTag(result, providedAssetID, checkbox.checked);
    //       const xmlBuilder = new Builder({ headless: true });
    //       const updatedXml = xmlBuilder.buildObject(result);
    //       await writeFile("salesforceResponse.xml", updatedXml);
    //     }
    //   }
    //   console.log("XML file updated successfully.");
    // } catch (err) {
    //   console.log("Error in saveValidationReport:", err);
    // }
});
```

When using:

```
debugger;
```

it seems to fail to go into the IF where there is an error invoking the function through the bridge.

I'm on OS X.

Comment: looks like it should work, but hard to tell. you probably need to make a minimal example yourself with something like electron quickstart repo and see if you can reproduce it there. have you tried sending a string like "hello" instead of the checkboxStates? is "window.api" maybe not available where you call it? you can add a console.log() in the preload function call too. But be aware that you cannot import any regular modules in preload script. no hint in devTools console? do console.logs() before and after     window.api.saveValidationReport(checkboxStates); trigger?

Comment: if you cannot get an answer here, you may want to try the official electron discord to seek for help: https://discord.gg/electronjs

Comment: @Welcor i did console log successfully all the 3 steps i described but otherwise when compiled the 2nd step 

ipcMain.handle('callSaveValidationReport', async (event, checkboxStates) 

doesnt get triggered or invoked in terms of electron.

Comment: using `debugger;` both in dev and compiled i get to this point in the rendered_edit js

`a.invoke = async function(e, ...t) {`

 and seems to return allright, i say seems cause calls the function in dev enviroment but not compiled

Comment: maybe your preload path is wrong. it has to be an absolute path. relative path may work with a dev mode web server but on with a prod packaged app.